# fprintf has last print statement printing to standard out

Tags: c, printf, fopen, freopen

```
void print_tree(tree_node *thestruct,int* fd,int numKids)
{    
    FILE *fo = freopen("output2.txt","w",stdout);
    printf("%s",thestruct->line);
    fflush(stdout);
    int i = 0;
    char buff[20];

    for(i=1; i < numKids+3; i++)
    {  
        bzero(buff,20);
        close(fd[2*i+1]);
        read(fd[2*i], buff, 20);
        close(fd[2*i]);
        printf("%s",buff);
        fflush(stdout);
    }   
}
```

basically in this line of code im trying to print the buffer from reads and writes when piping between processes. However the last print statement doesnt get printed to the file, instead getting printed to stdout? Ive tried using fprintf as well and the last print statement still comes out as

```
mgl70@ece29:~/ComputerSystems$ ./a.out processTree
D 0
```

in the terminal when I run the executable when i want

```
D 0
```

to be printed to the file

here are the writes

```
else{//child process stuff 
     close(fd[2*procNum]);
     char* line = strdup(initNode->line); 
     write(fd[2*procNum+1],line,20);
  }
```

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: What `fprintf` ?

Comment: ... especially because of the code comment `//child process stuff` so please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.